# Web API delete and put not working when hosted on shared hosting

Tags: web-services, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

My concern is that my web-api project that returns JSON works, very well locally, but when hosted on shared hosting

I already added this

`<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
 <remove name="WebDAVModule"/> 
 </modules>`

I also checked this 
http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2011/05/28/resolve-404-in-iis-express-for-put-and-delete-verbs.aspx

Checked the setting mentioned in this article as well and it was all there.

**DELETE and PUT - http://api.antheminfotech.net/api/employees/23 - 500 Error**

I have tired a lot of things, I am bit new to web-api so maybe I am missing somthing... or do i need a VPS hosting to have required access....

BTW I am using enitiy framework and creating a autogenerated controllers for this, based on EF models.

```
 Function PutEmpDetail(ByVal id As Integer, ByVal empdetail As EmpDetail) As HttpResponseMessage
    If Not ModelState.IsValid Then
        Return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState)
    End If

    If Not id = empdetail.Id Then
        Return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
    End If

    db.Entry(empdetail).State = EntityState.Modified

    Try
        db.SaveChanges()
    Catch ex As DbUpdateConcurrencyException
        Return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, ex)
    End Try

    Return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK)
End Function

 Function DeleteEmpDetail(ByVal id As Integer) As HttpResponseMessage
    Dim empdetail As EmpDetail = db.EmpDetails.Find(id)
    If IsNothing(empdetail) Then
        Return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
    End If

    db.EmpDetails.Remove(empdetail)

    Try
        db.SaveChanges()
    Catch ex As DbUpdateConcurrencyException
        Return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, ex)
    End Try

    Return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, empdetail)
End Function
```

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: http://api.antheminfotech.net/api/employees/23
I get internal server error, I call this with delete header.. I testing using chrome extenstion Advanced Rest Client

Comment: If you call this in the browser default get action is triggred and you see a list of users
http://api.antheminfotech.net/api/employees

Comment: Hard to tell with just "I get internal server error". I noticed you are on a shared hosting so you don't have access to the EventViewer.  Add some logging to your application that will allow you to do debugging - dump events to a log file.

Comment: I will try this, but what I am bit confused about is that are the calls reaching the functions in the first place... then only logging can work.

Comment: @vonv. I tried the logging, it seems the delete and put methods itself are not called on the server, if I call post the log is updated but on delete and put nothing happens... this is what i think is the major problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the probelm lied with the shared hosting, they where not able to bypass security and give the correct access.. I moved the API to a VPS and It worked seemlessly there.

Answer (score 1):

Typically on shared hosting these extra (and yes, they are extra) verbs are not enabled by default. System Administrators are loathe to add extras if 99.99% of the customer base doesn't need it enabled.

Consult with your host if they have it enabled. Likely they don't and, also likely, they may refuse to enable them. If so, ask them about alternatives, otherwise migrate to a different host.

Comment: I Tried that as well, I enabled the verbs but its seems there was additional security that they where not able to bypass, eventually It worked on a VPS system without any great difficulty.

Comment: Bear in mind, most likely it is not so much that they couldn't "bypass" additional security. It is that they have *disabled* the feature that 99% of customers don't even know is available in the specification. The feature is a security risk and, rather than that they can't "bypass" the rule to disable the feature, they are "enforcing" their rule that it may not be enabled.