# Delete Ajax works in localhost - but doesn't in production hosting

Tags: jquery, ajax, rest

I have a really strange bug.

In my local xampp's environment, the delete operation works great, the code is exactly the same, the database the same... And yet on hosting it doesn't work.

Code:

```
<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.0.0/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>

    <script>
      $.ajaxSetup({
          headers: {
              'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
          }
      });
    </script>    

        <script type="text/javascript">
        var theGrid = null;
        $(document).ready(function(){
            theGrid = $('#thegrid').DataTable({
                "processing": true,
                "serverSide": true,
                "ordering": true,
                "responsive": true,
                "ajax": "http://eindeks.000webhostapp.com/przedmioties/grid",
                "columnDefs": [
                    {
                        "render": function ( data, type, row ) {
                            return '<a href="http://eindeks.000webhostapp.com/przedmioties/'+row[0]+'">'+data+'</a>';
                        },
                        "targets": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "render": function ( data, type, row ) {
                            return '<a href="http://eindeks.000webhostapp.com/przedmioties/'+row[0]+'/edit" class="btn btn-default">Zaktualizuj</a>';
                        },
                        "targets": 4                    },
                    {
                        "render": function ( data, type, row ) {
                            return '<a href="#" onclick="return doDelete('+row[0]+')" class="btn btn-danger">Usuń</a>';
                        },
                        "targets": 4+1
                    },
                ]
            });
        });
        function doDelete(id) {
            if(confirm('Naprawdę chcesz usunąć ten wpis?')) {
               $.ajax({ url: 'http://eindeks.000webhostapp.com/przedmioties/' + id, type: 'DELETE'}).success(function() {
                theGrid.ajax.reload();
               });
            }
            return false;
        }
    </script>
```

The same is on local's end (e.g. `$.ajax({ url: 'http://localhost/dziennik/public/przedmioties/' + id, type: 'DELETE'})`)

But as you can see there is an Ajax with DataTables and it works well on both hosting and localhost.

But deletion doesn't work on my hosting's website.

Why? I don't know and I can't figure it out.

It's about this code I think:

```
function doDelete(id) {
            if(confirm('Naprawdę chcesz usunąć ten wpis?')) {
               $.ajax({ url: 'http://eindeks.000webhostapp.com/przedmioties/' + id, type: 'DELETE'}).success(function() {
                theGrid.ajax.reload();
               });
            }
            return false;
        }
```

But really, it's exactly the same (url different) on my localhost wherein which it is working. But on hosting it is not.

Okay, let's see the requests from the browser...

Localhost:

[image]

Yea, looks good, normal, and works. Nice!

But what on hosting?

[image]

What the... This is so weird. Just, I am looking at this and have no idea what is going on.

There is no response here:

[image]

And this xhr request has failed:

[image]

[image]

Ajax request is the same, code is the same, database is the same, both route ends working... I can't figure it out.

So what is the problem here?

Comment: In the 2nd pic, what does the response tab show?

Comment: If you're running this page externally and expecting `http://eindeks.000webhostapp.com` to receive AJAX, you would have to have [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) Access. In short, you can't control their site unless they let you.

Comment: @MehdiBounya empty response, updated the post

Comment: @PHPglue the xhr origin is the same site as seen in xhr request

Comment: Can you see if the request is reaching the server? and also what is the logs there? Are you using Apache or Nginx on prod? Are apache configs same?

Comment: @TarunLalwani sadly I can't reach logs on this hosting. And the server is `Server:awex` (from response headers). Hosting is 000webhost

Comment: That could be a difference. Ask them if delete request is allowed on their server

Comment: I suggest you to contact your hosting provider regarding this concern because I have found that PUT and DELETE methods are blocked in shared hosting.

Comment: Just have a look at this link, it's hosting provider issue

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15898059/web-api-delete-and-put-not-working-when-hosted-on-shared-hosting

Comment: enable errors on the hosting and check the logs

Comment: in firefox press ctrl+shift+E and see the response. check if there is CORS error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It could very well be that your server is configured not to allow `DELETE` requests or some of the other HTTP1.1+ verbs. In any case, HTML forms themselves don't allow `PUT`, `PATCH`, or `DELETE` actions. While these should work in JavaScript, it is worth giving [form method spoofing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#form-method-spoofing) a try in your AJAX request. This will circumvent any configuration your server might have that would block such a request and also work whether you're using a form or AJAX.

If you're still not getting a response, you'll need to start debugging by looking through Apache access and error logs and eventually bubbling up to the framework if necessary.

Answer (score 4):

1 - It might be that DELETE is disabled by the hosting provider. Ask the hosting provider whether DELETE is enabled. If you have access to apache check whether [WebDAV](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dav.html) module is enabled and if not, enable it.

2 - It might be CORS issue as well. Is CORS enabled on API. Send CORS headers with your request to API.
[barryvdh/laravel-cors](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors) is a great package for Laravel APIs for this purpose.

3 - Try changing type to POST and adding _method="DELETE" to the request. like this

```
$.ajax({ 
         url: 'http://eindeks.000webhostapp.com/przedmioties/' + id, 
         type: 'POST',
         data: {_method: 'delete'},
```

Answer (score 2):

Does your host allow `DELETE` requests? I̶f̶ ̶n̶o̶t̶,̶ ̶y̶o̶u̶ ̶c̶o̶u̶l̶d̶ ̶r̶e̶f̶a̶c̶t̶o̶r̶ ̶y̶o̶u̶r̶ ̶c̶o̶n̶t̶r̶o̶l̶l̶e̶r̶ ̶a̶n̶d̶ ̶a̶d̶d̶ ̶a̶n̶ ̶a̶c̶t̶i̶o̶n̶ ̶p̶a̶r̶a̶m̶e̶t̶e̶r̶,̶ ̶f̶o̶r̶ ̶e̶x̶a̶m̶p̶l̶e̶,̶ ̶a̶n̶d̶ ̶`̶P̶O̶S̶T̶`̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶r̶e̶q̶u̶e̶s̶t̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶y̶o̶u̶r̶ ̶s̶e̶r̶v̶e̶r̶.̶ ̶ ̶ ̶

̶ ̶ ̶f̶u̶n̶c̶t̶i̶o̶n̶ ̶s̶t̶o̶r̶e̶(̶R̶e̶q̶u̶e̶s̶t̶ ̶$̶r̶e̶q̶u̶e̶s̶t̶,̶ ̶$̶a̶c̶t̶i̶o̶n̶ ̶=̶ ̶'̶s̶t̶o̶r̶e̶'̶)̶ ̶{̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶i̶f̶ ̶(̶$̶a̶c̶t̶i̶o̶n̶ ̶=̶=̶=̶ ̶'̶s̶t̶o̶r̶e̶'̶)̶ ̶{̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶/̶/̶ ̶s̶t̶o̶r̶e̶ ̶n̶e̶w̶ ̶r̶e̶c̶o̶r̶d̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶}̶ ̶e̶l̶s̶e̶ ̶i̶f̶ ̶(̶$̶a̶c̶t̶i̶o̶n̶ ̶=̶=̶=̶ ̶'̶d̶e̶l̶e̶t̶e̶'̶)̶ ̶{̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶/̶/̶ ̶d̶e̶l̶e̶t̶e̶ ̶r̶e̶c̶o̶r̶d̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶}̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶}̶

Edit: method spoofing

Comment: You actually do not need to refactor the controller if that's the case. Laravel provides [form method spoofing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#form-method-spoofing) to handle such a scenario.

Answer (score 2):

You need to approach the problem step by step.
The first step is making sure that your server can receive the request properly.
Whenever I need to do that, I use this code:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode([
    'method' => $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'],
    'uri' => $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],
    'body' => file_get_contents('php://input'),
    'headers' => getallheaders(),
], JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES|JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE|JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Save the code as index.php and make a request to it.
For instance, with curl:

```
curl -XDELETE http://example.com/index.php
```

If your server is working properly, you should get a response similar to this:

```
{
    "method": "DELETE",
    "uri": "/index.php",
    "body": "",
    "headers": {
        "Host": "example.com",
        "User-Agent": "curl/7.53.1",
        "Accept": "*/*"
    }
}
```

If not, then you know where the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code instead of the current yours on doDelete

```
 function doDelete(id) {
        if (confirm('Naprawdę chcesz usunąć ten wpis?')) {
           $.ajax({ 
             url: 'http://eindeks.000webhostapp.com/przedmioties/' + id, 
             type: 'POST',
             data: {_method: 'delete'},
           }).success(function() {
               theGrid.ajax.reload();
           });
        }
        return false;
 }
```

That will make laravel router go to the delete action without the need of support in the server of the DELETE verb.